# Iteration in asynchronous programming (Node.js)

Tags: node.js, async.js

I want to iterate insert to db. Right after the iteration is done, I want to generate success message and redirect user to the specific page. That's why I use async package.
Here's my code:

```
async.forEachOf(venue_1_split, function (venue, key, callback) {

pool.query("INSERT INTO peminjaman_venue VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", 
                        [id_event, venue, id_google_calendar, waktu_mulai_1, waktu_selesai_1, tanggal_peminjaman_1, tanggal_peminjaman_1],
                        function(err, rows, fields){
                            if (err) throw err;
                        });

                            req.flash('message_success', 'Berhasil mengajukan event');
                            callback(res.redirect('/pengajuan_event'));
                        }, function (err) {
                            if (err) console.error(err.message);

                        });
```

It works but seems to be not correct. First, it returns error `

> "Can't set headers after they are sent"

And when i checked my db it only inserted 2 rows. The loop stopped on 2nd iteration. Can you fix my code. Thank you.

`

Comment: Node style callbacks expect `(error, result)`  so instead of throwing the error you should `return callback(err)` and instead of `callback(res. . .)` you should `callback(null, <some data>);` and then only in the final callback you should call methods on `res`

Answer (score 1):

You are redirecting to `/pengajuan_event` after every insert. Try following code.

```
async.forEachOf(venue_1_split, 
  function (venue, key, callback) {
    pool.query("INSERT INTO peminjaman_venue VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", 
      [
        id_event, 
        venue, 
        id_google_calendar, 
        waktu_mulai_1, 
        waktu_selesai_1, 
        tanggal_peminjaman_1, 
        tanggal_peminjaman_1
      ],
      callback(err, rows, fields)
    )}, function (err) {
      if(err) {
        console.error(err.message);
      } else {
        req.flash('message_success', 'Berhasil mengajukan event');
        res.redirect('/pengajuan_event')
      }
    }
);
```

Comment: the iteration works well, but the redirect message not executed @mandar.gokhale

Comment: I also replaced callback() with function(err, rows, fields){
         if(err) throw err;
        }